# make4ht xr-hyper and hyperref unable to compile

Tags: hyperref, make4ht, multiple-files, xr-hyper

Similar to [xr-hyper and cleveref unable to compile with make4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678730/xr-hyper-and-cleveref-unable-to-compile-with-make4ht), the following example compiles with `pdflatex` but fails to compile with `make4ht`

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}
\section{First Section} \label{section}
\begin{equation} \label{equation}
    \int f(x) dx
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`ref.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\externaldocument[main-]{main}

\begin{document}

    \hyperref[main-equation]{The equation in main}.

\end{document}
```

Running `make4ht main.tex` and then `make4ht ref.tex` gives the errors

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./ref.tex    10   Argument of \xr:rEfLiNK has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./ref.tex    10   Paragraph ended before \xr:rEfLiNK was complete.
```

I presume the solution will be similar to the cleveref solution.

#### Edit / Addition

If I add `\usepackage{xr-hyper}` to `main.tex` then both files compile, but there is no `href` attribute in the link in the `ref.html` file - the body of `ref.html` is just

```html
<p class='...'><a>The equation in main</a></p>
```

Comment: This code works for me with the latest update of TeX Live - it compiles without errors, and the link in `ref.html` works. So distro update should hopefully fix it.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks - this works with the new 2023 release, but didn't work with version 2022.62922.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this compiles with the 2023 version of Tex Live, but not the 2022 version.